# How to launch ATG application from Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, integration, atg

How to integrate ATG framework with eclipse so that i can run ATG application from eclipse and debug it using  eclipse debugging plugins ? which development tools do you use when developing ATG application? Thanks in advance for any helps from you.
Regards!

Comment: I am new to ATG but I am not unable to find plugin please help me where to find it I using ATG 10.0

Comment: @didxga , Have you ever cracked how to solve this?

Comment: @Buddha, please check answers provided by others. I haven't been using ATG for years now.

Comment: @didxga Thanks, But none of them really answer the question of how to run them from eclipse, I know debugging, so I was wondering if you had some luck. Best of luck with what ever you are working with right now.

Comment: @Buddha, Thanks, I hope you will work out eventually!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ATG support site [does mention an ATG Eclipse plugin](http://www.d2c2.com.tw/app_server_support.htm), (already developed and reported in [2003, and 2005](http://www.vasanth.in/2005/01/06/eclipse-plugin-atgforeclipse/)).
You have to check the [ATG supported environments](http://www.atg.com/en/ecommerce-suite/platform/supported-environments/index.jhtml?_requestid=19066) though.

Comment: Eclipse plugin is meant mostly for development tasks such as creating new module or providing snippets of code. It adds "ATG Nature" to the project which can e.g. show Nucleus components and configuration. IMHO, not as good as using ACC or /dyn/admin though - but available when ATG server is not running

Answer (score 4):

Best way would be start JBoss via external tool command using either usual run or adding 'startDynamoOnJBOss' script to external commands and make sure the JPDA is activated in run.conf or run.bat

After that, just connect with debugger to external Java process

Comment: I was trying to do this.Can you help me here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17721157/atg-jboss-project-in-eclipse

Answer (score 0):

By launch, I am assuming that you just want to start using Jboss. if so, you can do you by integrating Eclipse with one of the Web Tools Project pluggins. This comes along with Eclipse by default in most recent versions. You can configure server starup options as well. Please refer to the following link.

http://ist.berkeley.edu/as-ag/tools/howto/jboss-eclipse.html

Answer (score 0):

If you are using weblogic, go the startWeblogic.cmd , setDebugPort=8000 and debugFlag = true