# ATG-JBoss project in eclipse

Tags: jboss, atg, atg-dynamo

I have created a sample ATG project in eclipse. This is the way I followed.

File->New->Project-> ...atg wizards->New ATG Module

`Next->`put project name as  `MyFirstATGApp`  and select ed root diretory as `C:\ATG\ATG10.1.2`
`Next->Default  atg adaptive senario engine is selected.`
`Next->Next->` changed "Default output folder" value as " MyFirstATGApp /classes" 
`Next->set J2EE application Name= MyFirstATGApp-j2ee, Web application name= MyFirstATGApp-web, Context-root= MyFirstATGApp`  and selected `Target Applicaton Server=Jboss`
Then `Finish`.

From command prompt  from `C:\ATG\ATG10.1.2 \home\bin` I tried executing `startDynamoOnJBOSS -f MyFirstATGApp`
I am getting following error.Also I didn’t find a  `startDynamoOnJBOSS` inside the bin. Why is this happening??

[image]

I am new to ATG.Can I have any link with step-by-step ATG-Jboss-Eclipse project available?

Comment: Have you checked the %ATG_HOME%\bin folder? You will probably find a startDynamoOnTomcat.bat file there instead.

Comment: @radimpe: `startDynamoOnTomcat` is there.I am looking for ` startDynamoOnJBOSS` . I have configured JBoss server.

Comment: Does your project exist in %ATG_HOME%/servers/MyProject1? Does it have a startDynamoOnJBOSS.bat file in there? I've created the CRS project and I have the startDynamoOnJBOSS.bat file in my %ATG_HOME%/servers/ATGProduction/ folder. (Never been a big fan of the plugin. I'd much rather unpack the ATGProduction folder into a project and work from there).

Comment: NO.. for your questions. But I had configured JBoss successfully. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you didn't find the startDynamoOnJBOSS then there is some problem with your installation of jboss or atg.
but still you can run your project you just need to create ear of your project and paste it in your server deploy folder and start jboss.

For Detail You can read **ATG Platform Programming Guide**

Answer (score 3):

`startDynamoOnJBOSS` is no longer available in the ATG 10.2 bin.

To start your server, just create your EAR using `runAssembler` inside the deploy folder for your JBOSS server and call

```
run.bat -c <ServerName>
```

Answer (score 1):

startDynamoOnJBOSS is no longer exists in ATG version 10. Before running your project you need to deploy   your project in deploy folder of default or your created server instance using runAssembler

```
cd C:\ATG\ATG10.1.2\home\bin 
runAssembler C:\jboss-eap-5.1.2\jboss-as\server\default\deploy\MyFirstATGApp.ear -m MyFirstATGApp
```

Then run that server instance where ear file of your project is deployed

```
cd C:\jboss-eap-5.1.2\jboss-as\bin 
run -c default
```